# Get Warning Message Using rbokeh in R Notebook

Tags: r, rnotebook, rbokeh

Running Ubuntu 17.10, and running R Notebook on RStudio through Anaconda.

When I try to run the simple example from the [rbokeh website](http://hafen.github.io/rbokeh/#preview) in a R Notebook :

```
p <- figure() %>%
  ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris,
            color = Species, glyph = Species,
            hover = list(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
```

I get the following warning message:

```
In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :    
Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
```

It seems as if this warning message has been documented [here](https://github.com/bokeh/rbokeh/issues/216), but I'm still getting this warning. Does anyone have any recommendations on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/bokeh/rbokeh/issues/216

If you follow this link and use "devtools" to install from hafen/rbokeh, you no longer receive the warning message.

Comment: you mean devtools::install_github("hafen/rbokeh")