# Rbokeh barplot reordered by x-axis

Tags: r, bar-chart, rbokeh

Here is a simple example of barplot expressed in Rbokeh.

```
library(rbokeh)

# total yield per variety
figure() %>%
  ly_bar(variety, yield, data = lattice::barley, hover = TRUE) %>%
  theme_axis("x", major_label_orientation = 90)
```

Result are shown as below

[image]

**Question 1)**
I want to plot bars, reordered on x-axis by yield in descending order

I know that there's simple way of doing this in ggplot with 'reorder' function, but have no idea how to do this in Rbokeh.

How can I do this?

**Question 2)**
 Running the code above, I can see this error message, what does this mean and how can I solve this problem?

```
Warning messages:
1: In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
2: In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
3: In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
4: In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
5: In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
6: In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
7: In structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question: you can control the ordering of categorical axes by specifying the order in the `xlim`[*](https://github.com/bokeh/rbokeh/issues/206).  But first you should group "variety".  I did:

```
barley_data <- lattice::barley %>% 
  group_by(variety) %>% 
  summarise(yield = sum(yield))
```

Then, generate the plot:

```
figure(xlim = barley_data$variety[order(-barley_data$yield)]) %>%
  ly_bar(variety, yield, data = barley_data, hover = TRUE) %>%
  theme_axis("x", major_label_orientation = 90)
```

For the second question, perhaps you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659410/get-warning-message-using-rbokeh-in-r-notebook).